# Extend Sitecore xConnect web API

Tags: xdb, xconnect

My requirement is to add more custom data in the xConnect web API response.

For example, when I hit **https://xConnect-domain/odata/Contacts** then it gives me the default JSON for the contacts only, like below:

```
{  
   "@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Contact",
   "IsKnown":true,
   "Id":"a5a9d2dd-bf85-0000-0000-052ddc0cf60e",
   "ConcurrencyToken":"6c500c86-c9c6-4d76-b91f-f065495bdc0a",
   "LastModified":"2018-01-16T21:12:30.461158Z"
}
```

But I want to add more information related to the contacts like his few custom properties (e.g., company name, membership type), for example, it should be like:

```
{  
   "@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Contact",
   "IsKnown":true,
   "Id":"a5a9d2dd-bf85-0000-0000-052ddc0cf60e",
   "ConcurrencyToken":"6c500c86-c9c6-4d76-b91f-f065495bdc0a",
   "LastModified":"2018-01-16T21:12:30.461158Z",
   "PremeiumMember": "Yes",
   "Company": "Microsoft"
}
```

Please suggest how to achieve this?